# Using Listener in a different Class

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtree

I have a MainInterface and some other Classes.
The other Classes are GUI-Elemnts which I add to the MainInterface.
In the TreeClass I use a Tree for selecting diffrent things. In this Class i have a TreeListener to react on TreeSelection.

My goal is, that when I select something in the Tree, that the MainInterface react based on the Selection.
I have to Classes next to the named one (JPanel Red and JPanel Blue). Based on the Selection the two Classes (extends JPanel) have to appear.

I tried this already with Buttons in the MainInterface and it worked. But what i dont know how to do is, that the two Classes switch based on the TreeSelectionListener in the TreeClass ... so my main Problem is, that I dont know how the MainInterface listen to the Tree ...

Comment: [This](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-08/01-qa-0804-events.html) article might help

Comment: i would try it from the other side.
the tree should perform an action on the main interface.
write an method in the mainInterface, which switch the panels and invoke that method from the listener.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `MainInterface` should register itself as a [tree selection listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeselectionlistener.html) to your tree's model. There's an example at the bottom of the page.